# Decrypting .net 4.5 ScriptResources URL

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I have a need to decrypt the d from a ScriptResource.axd url in a different application using current .net 4.5 code.

Example url:

```
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=uBiLKmMIzkaavHlylMEgvqJFJuEnTqx-mMCevtyiy0KtaoGntw3zkVxSf9-7vVftEoviBYTu9G9pNcPMBekA8w_3HIQ-FHgM7KrekUC12jp66gU79E1WTxXaeLES1gLuYI01XfoaNBuGce8VFhZVkrsFwxC8--M7hcL2HMwOIJZBLW9w0&amp;t=ffffffffc8b7aa56" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Based on [Cryptographic Improvements in ASP.NET 4.5, pt. 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/10/23/cryptographic-improvements-in-asp-net-4-5-pt-2/) I need to call [MachineKey.Unprotect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.unprotect?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with a purpose.

I found the purpose I think in the .net source code ["ScriptResourceHandler.ScriptResourceUrl"](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/4fe4349175f4c5091d972a7e56ea12012f1e7170/System.Web/Security/Cryptography/Purpose.cs)

My machine key (sanitized) matches on both the server (that generates the url) and my local machine (for testing).

```
<machineKey validationKey="HEX" decryptionKey="HEX" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" compatibilityMode="Framework45"/>
```

My decryption code looks like:

```
public static string Decrypt(string encrypted, string purpose = "ScriptResourceHandler.ScriptResourceUrl")
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encrypted))
        return string.Empty;

    try
    {
        var bytes = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(encrypted);
        if (bytes != null && bytes.Length > 0)
        {
            var decryptedBytes = MachineKey.Unprotect(bytes,new string [] { purpose });
            if (decryptedBytes != null && decryptedBytes.Length > 0)
                return Encoder.GetString(decryptedBytes);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

The output I get is `Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.` and I've been unable to step into the .net source code to figure out anything more.

If I target framework 2.0 with the compatibilityMode I can make it work but this causes minor security concerns.

Any thoughts on getting this working with 4.5.2?